# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express Service Broker is using all free memory

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, service-broker

I have a database running on a machine that serves the purpose of updating information on a second by second basis. All of my clients provided data all come back to one source, which in turn publishes the data to the database. All this is fine, the problem I am having is with my service broker and listening to changes.

I am using the SqlDependency object to register listeners for specific queries. I get the events as expected, however the server eventually becomes unusable. I was able to determine the Service Broker is using over 900MB of memory (pushing me over the 1GB limit for express). I have the impression that my events are staying in memory and not clearing out. Every time I get an event, I clear out that event listener and register a new one. Is there a more proper way to clean up that event from the database?

Also, I have read all over that you have to call Stop and Start every time you register a new event. In my experience, calling stop a second time always hangs forever. Also, if stop clears all events, I have multiple listeners and I wouldnt want to halt the other ones when I receive one.

Here is the code I am using to register and respond to events:

```
using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.DatabseEventConnectionString))
{
    using (SqlCommand cmd = cn.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Field1, Field2, Field3, Field4 FROM dbo.Table";
        cmd.Notification = null;

        SqlDependency dep = new SqlDependency(cmd);
        dep.OnChange += new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

        cn.Open();

        using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
           // Handle read here;
        }
    }
}

void dependency_OnChange(object sender, SqlNotificationEventArgs e)
{
    // If InvokeRequired returns True, the code
    // is executing on a worker thread.
    if (Dispatcher.CheckAccess())
    {
        SqlDependency dep = sender as SqlDependency;
        dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
        RegisterTableListener();
    }
    else
    {

        // Create a delegate to perform the thread switch.
        OnChangeEventHandler tempDelegate =
            new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);

        object[] args = { sender, e };

        // Marshal the data from the worker thread
        // to the UI thread.
        Dispatcher.Invoke(tempDelegate, args);
    }
}
```

Any idea as to why the memory is forever climbing?

Comment: Been running tests and memory just never goes down. Even after closing my application with the events and calling stop after starting a new instance, the memory continues to climb and never releases.

Comment: We had a similar problem with service broker and I belive it was that the app was not ending the conversations it was creating.

Comment: Any idea how to actually close them out? The SqlDependency has no calls that can be made besides removing the event listener from OnChange. I have been spending all day trying to find ways to clean up after an event is received with no luck

Comment: Well I have backed off trying to use service broker. It appears SqlDepedency is not intended to be used in the manner I am trying to use it in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is specific behavior of Microsoft SqlDependency class. Even though you call SqlDependency.Stop() method, release SqlCommand and SqlConnection - it still keep conversation groups (sys.conversation_groups) and conversation endpoints (sys.conversation_endpoints) in the database. It looks like SQL Server loads every conversation endpoint and uses all allowed memory. [Here](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.UnitTests/SqlDependencyTest.cs) tests that prove it. So, to clean all unused conversation endpoints and release all occupied memory you have to start this SQL code for your database:

```
DECLARE @ConvHandle uniqueidentifier
DECLARE Conv CURSOR FOR
SELECT CEP.conversation_handle FROM sys.conversation_endpoints CEP
WHERE CEP.state = 'DI' or CEP.state = 'CD'
OPEN Conv;
FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0) BEGIN
    END CONVERSATION @ConvHandle WITH CLEANUP;
    FETCH NEXT FROM Conv INTO @ConvHandle;
END
CLOSE Conv;
DEALLOCATE Conv;
```

Also, SqlDependency doesn't give you an opportunity to receive ALL changes of the table. So, you don't receive notification about changes during SqlDependency resubscription.

To avoid all these problems I'd used another open source realization of SqlDependency class - [SqlDependencyEx](https://github.com/dyatchenko/ServiceBrokerListener/blob/master/ServiceBrokerListener/ServiceBrokerListener.Domain/SqlDependencyEx.cs). It uses database trigger and native Service Broker notification to receive events about changes of the table. This is an usage example:

```
int changesReceived = 0;
using (SqlDependencyEx sqlDependency = new SqlDependencyEx(
          TEST_CONNECTION_STRING, TEST_DATABASE_NAME, TEST_TABLE_NAME)) 
{
    sqlDependency.TableChanged += (o, e) => changesReceived++;
    sqlDependency.Start();

    // Make table changes.
    MakeTableInsertDeleteChanges(changesCount);

    // Wait a little bit to receive all changes.
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
}

Assert.AreEqual(changesCount, changesReceived);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I am not an expert, but...

Have you tried:

```
   using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
   {
      // Handle read here;
   }
```

and possibly changing 
       dep.OnChange -= new OnChangeEventHandler(dependency_OnChange);
       to
       dep.OnChange -= dependency_OnChange;

Comment: No luck. One thing to note is that the software calling the query is not hosting the memory, but the server itself. Basically need to find a way to close the SqlDependency event from the server after use.